# Refactoring generator code in a Python class

Tags: python, generator

I have a need to refactor the generator part of `run(self)` in the following class to a separate method so that it can be overriden in a subclass.

```
class First():
    def run(self):

        for item in list1:
            print(f"run2 in Second {item}")
            yield item

        print("run")
```

Below is my attempt but it doesn't work. The `self.run2()` part of the run method seems to have no effect. How do I properly do this?

```
list1 = [1,2,3]

class First():
    def run(self):
        self.run2()   #### This seems to be ignored.
        print("run")

    def run2(self):
        print("run2 in First")

class Second(First):
    def new(self):
        print("second new")

    def run2(self):
        for item in list1:
            print(f"run2 in Second {item}")
            yield item


class Third(Second):
    def some(self):
        pass

third = Third()
third.new()    ## outputs "second new"
third.run()    ## outputs "run", not "runs in Second xxx"
```

Comment: `yield from self.run2()`? You're currently just creating, not *entering*, the generator.

Comment: `self.run2()` returns a generator object. You have to consume the generator to get the actual loop code going.

Comment: Seems odd to override a function with a generator...

Comment: Thank you for your help! If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what behavior you expect? The result of the various run methods is ignored - why make them generators at all?